# Devxpress web Gridview load data on request

Tags: c#, aspxgridview

I'm developing a web page witch has an AspxTreelist and an ASPxGridView. I would like to fill the grid with data after selecting some nodes on treelist. The treelist nodes are filtering the grid data

Here is my code samples :

Here I'm getting the selected nodes

```
Categories = new List<int>();

foreach (TreeListNode node in categs)
{

     Categories.Add(int.Parse(node["Key"].ToString()));
}
```

And here I'm filling the grid

```
if (Categories!= null && Categories.Count > 0)
{

     DGEmails.DataSource = Manager.GetBySubTree(Categories);
     DGEmails.DataBind();
}
```

The problem is that after I get the Categories and fill the Grid's datasource (these parts work fine) there are not any data displaying on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, it was the fact that treelist by default uses callbacks and I had to disable them.